# How do I load a local html file into Jsoup?

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I can't seem to load in a local html file, using the Jsoup library. Or at the very least it doesn't seem to be recognising it. I hardcoded the exact html in the local file (as the var 'html') and when I switch to that instead of a file input the code works perfectly. But the file is read on both occasions.

```
import java.io.File;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;


public class FileHtmlParser{

public String input;


//constructor
public FileHtmlParser(String inputFile){input = inputFile;}


//methods
public FileHtmlParser execute(){

    File file = new File(input);
    System.out.println("The file can be read: " + file.canRead());

    String html = "<html><head><title>First parse</title><meta>106</meta> <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" /></head>"
              + "<body><p>Parsed HTML into a doc.</p>" +
              "" +
              "<div id=\"navbar\">this is the div</div></body></html>";
            Document doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(input);




    Elements content = doc.getElementsByTag("div");
    if(content.hasText()){System.out.println("result is " + content.outerHtml());}
    else System.out.println("nothing!");


    return this;
}

}/*endOfClass*/
```

**Result when:

Document doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(html)**

```
The file can be read: true
result is <div id="navbar">
this is the div
</div>
```

**Result when:

Document doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(input)**

```
The file can be read: true
nothing!
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your mistake is in assuming that `Jsoup.parseBodyFragment()` knows whether you're passing it a filename that contains html markup or a string that contains the html markup.

`Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(input)` expects that `input` is a `String` that contains html markup, not a filename.

To ask it to parse from a file use the `Jsoup.parse(File in, String charsetName)` method instead:

```
File in = new File(input);
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(in, null);
```

Comment: Update: in my original answer I mistakenly passed in the string ``input`` instead of the ``File`` object ``in``.  Also you'll have to wrap the code in a ``try-catch`` block to make it work.

Comment: Any idea how to use this in Android where the file is in the assets folder?

Answer (score 1):

This is for Kotlin users; pretty much like the Java version:

```kotlin
val file = File("my-document.html")
val document = Jsoup.parse(file, "UTF-8")
```

Here is the [documentations for this method](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/load-document-from-file).