# How to save the xhtml file in jsoup

Tags: java

I need to be able to manipulate the content of an xhtml file  then write everything back to an xhtml file. Is it possible with Jsoup ?

Comment: Let us know what you have tried, so that others can better help you. Also be a bit more elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

To read:
[How do I load a local html file into Jsoup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9611570/how-do-i-load-a-local-html-file-into-jsoup)

```
File in = new File(input);
Document doc = JSoup.parse(in, null);
```

Do something with that !

To save: [How to save a Jsoup Document to an HTML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24696766/how-to-save-a-jsoup-document-to-an-html-file)

```
File f = new File(output);
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(f, doc.outerHtml(), "UTF-8");
```